# How do I type lodash/fp curried functions?

Tags: lodash, flowtype

I'm trying to add to the flow-typed typings. I'm starting with the `lodash/fp` module because that is most useful to myself. However, I'm struggling with how to type it correctly.

A simple example if `dropRightWhile`:

```
declare function dropRightWhile<T>(iteratee: (val: T)=>boolean, data?: Array<T>): Array<T> | (data: Array<T>)=>Array<T>;
```

This is my attempt to type it. `dropRightWhile` must take an iteratee, and it could take the data. If you don't give it data then it returns a function that takes the data, but if you give it data then it returns an array.

The type I have made doesn't strictly make the connection between number of arguments and return type. However, when I try to use a curried `dropRightWhile` I get an error

`var c = dropRightWhile((x) => x> 0); c([0, 1, 2, 3]);`
`error: Function cannot be called on array type`

I would've thought that since `dropRightWhile` can return a function then I would be able to call it, but it seems the array type is getting in the way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define 2 overloadings

```
declare function dropRightWhile<T>(iteratee: (val : T) => boolean, data : Array<T>) : Array<T>;
declare function dropRightWhile<T>(iteratee: (val : T) => boolean): (data : Array<T>) => Array<T>;

// tests
const iteratee = x => x > 0;
(dropRightWhile(iteratee)([0, 1, 2, 3]) : Array<number>);
(dropRightWhile(iteratee, [0, 1, 2, 3]) : Array<number>)
```